# Error in installing different version of rubygems through RPMs

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems, rpm

I have been trying to install rubygems through RPMs (because my target machine doesn't have an internet connection). Now I need to install both json-1.8.1 and json-1.6.8 gems. I have generated RPMs for both the versions though fpm. I installed both of them, but only one of them is visible in gem list.

```
# rpm -q rubygem-json
rubygem-json-1.8.1-1.x86_64
rubygem-json-1.6.8-1.x86_64
```

The gem list shows only one version installed.

```
# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

json (1.8.1)
```

Now, when I did yum check, the output is:

```
# yum check
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
rubygem-json-1.8.1-1.x86_64 is a duplicate with rubygem-json-1.6.8-1.x86_64
Error: check all
```

I am able to install different versions of some of the gems like puma, mime-types. But I am having issues with json.
How can I install both the versions, so that the dependencies can be resolved?

Comment: It can be done only avoiding the RPM dependencies, use the gemset support property of *rvm* or *rbenv* apps. But anyway, are those version needed to be used both in a single project? If yes, it will introduce into ythe project inconsistency.

Comment: Yeah, I actually need both of them. I will try to look into rvm.